# how send a file with app inventor?

Tags: php, android, app-inventor

how send a file with app inventor? Do you know examples or tutorial for PostFile? I try this:

```
Button1.clik
Web1.Url to http://mysite.com/test.php
web1.PostFile path Image1.Picture
Web1.PostText text this is my image
```

But in my test.php What do I write?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this tread might help you find the answer your looking for https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/app-inventor-php-api-services/6WuJ-azfbSQ . i hope that helps

Comment: KC's link moved to another location: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/app-inventor-developers-library/Sc4a1wZHL-Q/discussion